# Emacs CEDET setup doubt

Tags: emacs, cedet

I installed cedet successfully today and got most of it working; thanks to Alex Ott's [Gentle Introduction to Cedet](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html).

However i am having a problem

When I give the exact path relative to the current file i am working on then auto-completion is working fine.

```
#include "../../opensource/inc/lldp_port.h"
void test_func()
{
    lldp_port port;
    port.blah //here auto-completion worked fine
}
```

However i cannot specify the full path all the time( we have eclipse at office and it generates makefiles for us )

```
#include "lldp_port.h"
void test_func()
{
    lldp_port port;
    port. //here auto-completion does not work :(
}
```

What should i do to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

One of the arguments to CEDET's project setup function is `include-path`. There's an example [here](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/projects.shtml):

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "NAME" :file "FILENAME"
     :include-path '( "/include" "../include" "/c/include" )
     :system-include-path '( "/usr/include/c++/3.2.2/" )
     :spp-table '( ("MOOSE" . "")
                   ("CONST" . "const") )
     :spp-files '( "include/config.h" )
     )
```

Comment: just correction: system-include-path is usually detected automatically via semantic-gcc, but it could be used to specify path to other libraries, not included into project